# KeyPairGenerator is not generating random keys

Tags: java, rsa

Im generating RSA keypair with KeyPairGenerator and ive noticed that all the time its generating exactly matching keys, not random ones like it should be? Maybe anyone have some ide why could that be?

My code looks like this right now:

```
private static KeyPair generateKeyPair(Provider provider, int keySize) throws Exception
{

    KeyPair keyPair = null;

    /* get the eracom keystore - access to the adapter */
    //KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("CRYPTOKI", provider.getName());
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", provider.getName());

    keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySize);
    keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

    return keyPair;
}
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:
It was issue with the HSM and the provider i use. Look at the comment on Joachim Sauer reply.

Comment: What does your code look like that you are using to generate the keys?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  An SSCCE would be able to tell me, and others, if the method is being called many times in quick succession.  That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a slightly modified version of your code (to get it to compile) works just fine (i.e. produces different keys when run multiple times:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
System.out.println(keyPair.getPrivate());
System.out.println(keyPair.getPublic());
```

Is it possible that the provider you use is ... ill-behaving? What's the value of `provider.getName()`?

Comment: Yes, looks like this is a provider issue. I dont have hardware HSM on this machine so running in software mode. From the HSM manual: "The random parameter is ignored as the hardware
includes a cryptographically-secure random source." It doesnt say what happens when running in software mode. Just had to remove the provider name from .getInstance to get it to generate random keys.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. The code that worked for me is:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");    
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
keyGen.initialize(1024,random);
KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Now print them to check for yourself if the keys are different using:

```
System.out.println(key.getPrivate());
System.out.println(key.getPublic());
```

The SecureRandom generator creates a new random number using the given algorithm (SHA1PRNG) in this case and the privider (SUN in this case). You can find more information here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html
and api here : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize it. According to [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.crypto/asymmetric-encryption-keys-with-the-keypairgene-2.html) it should look something like:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: Yes i initialized it. Look at my code what i added to the first post.

Comment: @h2sd Based on the docs when you call iniitialize it should is a new inistance of SecureRandom as a default, but there is an option to pass an instance of secure random as a second parameter into the initialize method. You could try that to see if makes a difference.