# Can't get KeyPairGenerator to generate random keys

Tags: android, rsa, sha1, public-key-encryption, android-keystore

I'm trying to generate public/private RSA key pairs like so on Android to use for signing:

```
val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore")

val certStart = Calendar.getInstance()
val certEnd = Calendar.getInstance()
certEnd.add(Calendar.YEAR, 30)

val spec = KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
     .setAlias("MyKeyAlias")
     .setKeySize(1024)
     .setSubject(X500Principal("CN=CryptoIsHard"))
     .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
     .setStartDate(certStart.time)
     .setEndDate(certEnd.time)
     .build()

 keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"))
 keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
```

This works fine, and if I get the public key and convert it to hex it looks something like this:

```
30819F300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818D00308...
```

The problem is that when I'm testing this using android instrumentation tests running on AVDs, the key is **always the same**, which I didn't expect because I'm using something called SecureRandom as a source (I would have thought that would use something like the current time to help generate entropy?). I've tried wiping the data on the AVDs, using different AVDs, changing the alias, I always get the same key, suggesting it's using a static seed (this doesn't make any sense to me - the name of the class is SecureRandom, and it doesn't seem to be at all secure?)

There are a couple of similar questions which don't help:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352978/keypairgenerator-is-not-generating-random-keys): The suggestion here is to not specify a provider when getting the KeyPairGenerator instance. This doesn't seem to make any difference.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671353/unique-key-pair-generation-on-android): Apparently adding something called spongycastle as a provider solved the problem - I don't really want to add a 3rd party library to do this, especially one that looks like it's pretty ancient and no longer maintained

PS If I delete the key pair:

```
val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
keyStore.load(null)
keyStore.deleteEntry("MyKeyAlias")
```

And generate another key, I get a new and different key. But this obviously doesn't help - the *first* key is always the same.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect the `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")` but is crucial, but I don't know what to try. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the key is always the same? Hopefully not by eyeballing the first few bytes.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but best practices are to use `new SecureRandom()` rather than `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")`.

Comment: Oh my god. Sorry, you're right - they're not the same. I was eyeballing the head and tail. It turns out the first 30 or so bytes and the last 5 bytes are always the same, but everything in between is different (slaps hand on head). I totally didn't expect that - why is this?

Comment: Okay, so I've done a bit of research into RSA public key structure. I'm guessing this is because of metadata which isn't changing (eg the cert details), possibly even the "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" bit is included. Thanks for your help!